# Как получить список ip адресов всех активных сетевых адаптеров в Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, unix

Как получить список ip адресов всех активных сетевых адаптеров в Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого необходимо открыть терминал и выполнить команду

```
ifconfig
```

Comment: Это уже не тру :). Однако же, 2011й год на дворе!

Comment: sudo ifconfig

Answer (score 5):

```
ip addr list
```

Comment: Для ленивых просто ip a :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ifconfig | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | grep -v lo | awk '/flags/ {printf "Interface "$1" "} /inet/ {printf $2" "} /status/ {printf $2"\n"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ifconfig -a
```